# How to increase all integers in all the sublists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9]]`
to
`name_doesn't_matter = [[11,12,13,14],[15,16],[17,18,19]]`

and the number of sublists are the result of user input so the answer should be for any given number of sublists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehensions:

```
foo = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
bar = [[x + 10 for x in inner] for inner in foo]
```